# Oracle SQL randomising column entries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

| PC | A | MAXI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | A1 | 1 |
| PC1 | A2 | 2 |
| PC1 | A3 | 3 |
| PC2 | A1 | 1 |
| PC2 | A2 | 2 |
| PC2 | A3 | 3 |

Is there a way to generate 'MAXI' entries for each group of 'PC' and 'A' in a random order (or at least a seemingly even distribution, even if not random)?

Desired output (count_pc would just be an order count over partition by PC):

| PC | A | COUNT_PC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | A2 | 1 |
| PC1 | A1 | 2 |
| PC1 | A3 | 3 |
| PC1 | A3 | 4 |
| PC1 | A2 | 5 |
| PC1 | A3 | 6 |
| PC2 | A3 | 1 |
| PC2 | A2 | 2 |
| PC2 | A3 | 3 |
| PC2 | A1 | 4 |
| PC2 | A2 | 5 |
| PC2 | A3 | 6 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your rows using your favorite method, then use a random number generator for the last column (with `row_number()`):

```
with cte(pc, a, maxi) as (
      select pc, a, maxi
      from t
      union all
      select pc, a, maxi - 1
      from cte
      where maxi > 1
     )
select pc, a,
       row_number() over (partition by pc order by dbms_random.random) as count_pc
from cte
order by pc, count_pc;
```